# Convert date and time to milliseconds in C

Tags: c, datetime

I have a date and time value stored in a structure. I want to convert that into timestamp(milliseconds).

```
dt.year = 2016;
dt.month = 01;
dt.date = 11;
dt.hour = 17;
dt.minute = 14;
dt.seconds = 30;
dt.milliseconds = 345;
```

I used http://currentmillis.com/ to get the millisecond value for the above date and time and it returned the following value.

**1452512670345**

Is there any library function available in C to convert the above data time value as milliseconds?

Comment: What do you mean `how to`?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're looking for a reliable source code to do so, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because clearly a write my code request, not a question. Please read [Ask] page first. :)

Comment: yes. I need code sample or math logic to convert

Comment: It's not a "write my code" question: a pointer to the `mktime` function is sufficient answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mktime` will convert a `struct tm` into a Unix timestamp in seconds. Multiply by `1000` and add the extra milliseconds to the result.